# charset problem in wordpress because of nginx config

Tags: seo, nginx, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, post-editor

I transferred a WordPress website to my server, the previous webserver was apache, the new web server is Nginx, but I made a mistake and got the Nginx config file from my old resources
so this phrase "charset koi8-r;" left in the config file, I removed this phrase later

after the movement, I notice an error in WordPress create post page, in the console menu

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[б─-б©ц≈ц╥Б──-Б╞©Б╦─-Б╧©]/: Range out of order in character class
    at Module.<anonymous> (analyzer.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at n (analyzer.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at analyzer.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
    at analyzer.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
```

which didn't affect my work procedure and writing posts, until I notice that this error don't let the SEO plugins panel to be opened and usable, and when I try to use SEO plugins like Yoast SEO or Rank Math SEO, this error will be also in the console:
*this error is for Rank Math SEO and a similar error will be displayed for Yoast SEO*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: rankMathAnalyzer is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at n (classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at n (classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1)
    at classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
    at classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
(anonymous) @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
n @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
(anonymous) @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
n @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
(anonymous) @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
(anonymous) @ classic.js?ver=1.0.71.1:1
```

this situation isn't good, because I can't use SEO tools anymore, after lots of investigation I notice that when I change my site URL from **[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)** to something else like **beta.mysite.com** the error will not be displayed anymore and changing back to default address result in error appearing again

I tried whatever I could, clearing cache and other similar stuff, but I am on a dead-end road now,
I checked the database charset, changed my database version (MariaDB 10.4 and 10.5), changed PHP version (Php 7.4 and 8.0), and lots of other things
do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you've changed your charset to the correct value ( hopefully utf8 ) then I don't see how it could cause this? I do not believe your theory for the cause of this is correct. Have you checked your database has the correct charset and collation? Have you raised this with Yoast SEO? 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here and not allowed

Comment: yes I checked the database charset and collation both are correct, I even deleted all tables, created the database once again with the correct charset and collation, and imported data, I also checked the problem with Yoast Team, the error is still there even when I totally remove Yoast extension, I mean It's obviously for WordPress not any other plugin

Comment: Even with the correct Nginx charset and database charset despite redoing the migration? **What did Rankmath SEO say?** Does this affect any other functionality? How did you rule out that it isn't a bug shared by those 2 plugins?

Comment: A search suggests Koi8-r is a Russian language encoding, are you sure that you haven't mangled/broken the encoding during the migration? It's really difficult to diagnose this with so little information, have you checked the HTML source for broken Russian characters? The JS errors in your console on their own are not enough to solve the problem

Comment: `б─-б©ц≈ц╥Б──-Б╞©Б╦─-Б╧©` is detected as ukrainian by google translate but nothing is translated. I strongly suspect you have broken and mangled values somewhere as part of your migration effort. Perhaps when you exported the database you exported it into a character encoding that did not support the full character set, or you imported into the database with an encoding that did not support the characters, and they were truncated. This can happen if 8 byte characters are inserted into a 4byte encoding, they either get split or the ends are cut off

Comment: thank you for your help, appreciate it, I finally found the cause of the problem, the real cause of the problem was what I already found, the charset in Nginx config, and as you said "If you've changed your charset to the correct value ( hopefully utf8 ) then I don't see how it could cause this" the problem should be solved and it was, but the Cloudflare cache mislead me until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really can't believe this, but sometimes the answer is really simple
I just forgot to clear the Cloudflare cache

It's more than a week which I am trying to fix this problem O_o